# Can I reverse engineer an EXE file(compiled in C++) to get its source code?

Tags: c++, exe, reverse-engineering, source-code-protection

If yes, can someone point me in the right direction to where to start looking?

Comment: No you can't. Basically the .exe file contains machine code which cannot be translated back to C++ source code.